# In an Umbraco macro, how do I get the URL of a Media Picker image on the child page?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In an Umbraco macro template (.cshtml), I'm looping over the children of the current page:

```
var quadrants = startNode.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);
@foreach (var quadrant in quadrants){
```

and then rendering some of their attributes into the HTML:

```
@quadrant.GetPropertyValue("Title")
```

Now, one of the attributes is a Media Picker image. I'd like to print its URL into an `<img>` tag - but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
@quadrant.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("image").FirstOrDefault().Url
```